# ¿Cómo obtener el valor devuelto por un procedimiento almacenado en Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, stored-procedure

Tengo un **procedimiento almacenado en MySql**, el cual **devuelve un valor entero** al llamarlo.

Estoy tratando de llamar este procedimiento almacenado desde laravel y obtener el valor que retorna en una variable que pueda utilizar.

Si llamo al procedimiento de la siguiente forma:

```
$resultado = DB::select('select procedimiento(parametro));
```

Al realizar `dd($resultado)` obtengo:

```
array:1 [
  0 => {#670
    +"procedimiento('parametro')": 452
  }
]
```

siendo 452 el valor que busco.

¿Cómo puedo obtener este valor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No llames al procedimiento con "select ", llámalo con "CALL" :

```
        // Sentencia SQL de llamada al procedimiento
        $procsentence = "CALL procedimiento( :param1, :param2 )";

        $params = array();
        $params['param1'] = 'valor1';
        $params['param2'] = 'valor2';

        // Llamamos al procedimiento
        $res = DB::select($procsentence, $params);

        dd($res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Para acceder a un elemento por ejemplo a un conteo de registros debes asignar un alias por ejemplo :

Dentro del procedimiento

```
select count(*) as total from users;
```

Luego haciendo uso de tinker, comprobamos:

```
>>> $raw=DB::select('CALL count_users')
=> [
     {#3154
       +"total": 51,
     },
  ]
```

Entonces para acceder al "total" hacemos:

```
>>> $raw[0]->total
=> 51
```

Answer (score 0):

Hace tiempo que no utilizo laravel pero espero que te dés un día o si te pueda ayudar.

Podés intentar hacerlo siguiente y ver que resultado te muestra.
    print_r($resultado[0]);
    die();

o bien ejecutar tu procedimiento almacenado de esta manera y ver que te muestra

```
$resultado   =  DB::statement('procedimiento ?, ?', array($parametro1, $parametro2));
```

Recuerdo que de esta forma no me funcionó en su momento, pero podés probarlo.

```
$resultado   =  DB::select('exec procedimiento ?', array($parametro));
```

Saludos,